# how to add if-else logic in CSS file?

Tags: css, sass

I have the following .css.scss file

```
.book-list li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-left:5px;
    width:175px;
    color: #c4c5c7;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    font-size: 12px;
    &:first-child {
        width: 535px;
        margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
        padding: 0 0 5px 5px;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted #6b6a6c;
    }
}
```

Now I wish to style a very similar list called `.todo-list`.
The only differences are:

1. `.todo-list` li element has width of 125px instead of 175px.
2. `.todo-list` li element does **NOT** have the special styling for the `first-child`

I would style my html in the following way:

```
<ul class="book-list">
    <li>...
    </li>
    <li>...
    </li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul class="todo-list">
    <li>...
    </li>
    <li>...
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I achieve the above **without** duplicating the whole block?
(Essentially I'm looking for ways to add if-else condition in the css file.)

Thank you

Comment: What about putting common code in a Mixin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Abstract superclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877468/abstract-superclass)

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Mixins to re-use common code.

```
@mixin common-code {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  color: #c4c5c7;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.book-list li {
    width:175px;
    @include common-code;
    &:first-child {
        width: 535px;
        margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
        padding: 0 0 5px 5px;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted #6b6a6c;
    }
}

.todo-list li {
    width:125px;
    @include common-code;
}
```

As far as I know, there are no If-Else clauses in SASS or pure CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the CSS *attribute selector* and the `$=` operator (which means 'ends with'):

```
[class$="list"] li {
display: inline-block;
margin-bottom:5px;
margin-left:5px;
color: #c4c5c7;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
font-size: 12px;
}

.book-list li:first-child {
width: 535px;
margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
padding: 0 0 5px 5px;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #6b6a6c;
}

.book-list li {
width:175px;
}

.todo-list li {
width: 125px
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe that there is a way to add logic css files. You could do it using javascript, however a pure css solution is possible.

```
.book-list li, .todo-list li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-left:5px;
    color: #c4c5c7;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.book-list li {
    width: 175px;
    &:first-child {
        width: 535px;
        margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
        padding: 0 0 5px 5px;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted #6b6a6c;
    }
}

.todo-list li {
    width: 125px;
}
```

Note: In css the last property given to an element will be the one used. This means that you can style .todo-list li to overwrite the previous assignment of width and &:first child should you wish to do so.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. Properties are overriden only if the selector's priority is higher or equal. The priority is calculated like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: @ZackXu: yes, it will work if you put `width: 175px` in the first block. All block selectors have equal priority so the properties will be overriden.

Comment: This did not work for me.  The styling of `book-list` is lost for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance in Sass like:

```
.list {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-left:5px;

    color: #c4c5c7;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.book-list {
    @extend .list

    li {
        width: 125px;

        &:first-child {
            width: 535px;
            margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
            padding: 0 0 5px 5px;
            border-bottom: 1px dotted #6b6a6c;
        }
    }
}

.todo-list {
    @extend .list;

    li {
        width: 175px;
    }
}
```